# Generate String equals to given sum within given character

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, data-structures

Given two numbers n and k, find a string s of lowercase alphabets such that sum of values of all the elements in the string is equal to k. 
If there exist many such strings, find the one which is lexicographically the smallest.

The value of ith lowercase alphabet is i, for example, value of a is 1, b is 2, and so on.

Input format:
First line of input contain a single integer t, denoting number of test cases.
t lines follows each containing two space-separated integers n and k.

Output format:
Print the lexicographically smallest string of length n and having string sum value equal to k.

Constraints:

1 <= t <= 50

1 <= n <= 2*10^5

n <= k <= 26*n

Sample Input:

2

5 42

3 25

Sample Output:

aaamz

aaw

Explanation:

string value of aaamz is 42 also, it is smallest lexicographical string such that it contains 5 characters and has string value 42.

Comment: This appears to be a homework problem and questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work has been done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @irs102info is it possible that there exists any invalid results like for the case like this - 1 40 where n=1 and k=40, would a case like this ever exist ?

Comment: Do you have a link to the problem description, seems to be something that might have been posted online ?

Comment: @zenwraight, yeah we can have invalid results, in that case we have to print '-1'.  I don't have a link to that problem.

Comment: @LakshayGarg, This is my approach to solve the problem,
`char[] a = new char[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   a[i] = 'a'; 
  }
  int a_count = n;
  int tot_count = k;
  int x = tot_count - a_count;
  for(int i=n-1;i>=0; i--){
   if(x> 26){
    a[i] = 'z';
    x = (x-26)+1;
   }
   else if(x > 0){
    a[i] = (char) (a[i] + x);
    x = 0;
   }
   if(x == 0)
    break;
  }
  String op="";
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   op = op+a[i];
  }
  System.out.println(op);`

But I'm getting Time Limit Exceeds (TLE) error.
Is there any other thoughts or way to solve much quicker?

Comment: Can u add your code in proper syntax to ur answer post, it will be more readable then, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
generateLexicoString(int n, int k){
char[] a = new char[n];
    // Initially fill the array with character 'a'
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i] = 'a'; 
    }
    int a_count = n;
    int tot_count = k;
    int x = tot_count - a_count;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0; i--){
        if(x> 26){
            a[i] = 'z';
            x = (x-26)+1;
        }
        else if(x > 0){
            a[i] = (char) (a[i] + x);
            x = 0;
        }
        if(x == 0)
            break;
    }
    String op="";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        op = op+a[i];
    }
    System.out.println(op);
}
```

Comment: this program seems to be of O(n) and it should not give u TLE, hmm weird, because i don't think u can do anything better than this.

Comment: So u are getting TLE that means u are submitting this code to a problem online somewhere can u send the link to that submission or problem ?

Comment: @zenwraight Yeah, this is a contest hosted by our company as a part of programming practice and the link can't be shared with outsiders as per policy.

Comment: You are appending characters to a string inside a loop. This requires copying the entire string for every append and therefore is an O(n^2) operation. You can try using a stringstream or having a char array which you convert to std::string before returning which will make this an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid string append by using  "System.out.print(a[i]);" as below.

`for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       System.out.print(a[i]);
}`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, But I think accepted solution here is missing one case:

if n = 2, k=28.
then the solution should be "bz".

```
 generateLexicoString(int n, int k){
char[] a = new char[n];
    // Initially fill the array with character 'a'
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i] = 'a'; 
    }
    int a_count = n;
    int tot_count = k;
    int x = tot_count - a_count;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0; i--){
        if(x> 26){
            a[i] = 'z';
            x = (x-26)+1;
        }
        else if(x == 26){
            a[i] = (char) (a[i] + 25);
            x = 1;
        }
        else if(x > 0){
            a[i] = (char) (a[i] + x);
            x = 0;
        }
        if(x == 0)
            break;
    }
```

Char Array **a** will be our answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the solution provided above, it missed the case when x will be exactly 26. (This will fail for, say, n = 2 and k = 28).
So for that, a bit of modification is required.

```
generateLexicoString(int n, int k){
    char[] a = new char[n];
    // Initially fill the array with character 'a'
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i] = 'a'; 
    }
    int a_count = n;
    int tot_count = k;
    int x = tot_count - a_count;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0; i--){
        if(x> 26){
            a[i] = 'z';
            x = (x-26)+1;
        }
        else if(x == 26){
         a[i] = (char) (a[i] + 25);
          x = x - 25; 
        }
        else if(x > 0){
            a[i] = (char) (a[i] + x);
            x = 0;
        }
        if(x == 0)
            break;
    }
    String op= String.valueOf(a);
    System.out.println(op);
    // return op;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        int n,k;
        cin>>n>>k;

        string s="";

        for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
        {
            if(k - (i-1) > 26)
            {
                s = 'z' + s;
                k-=26;
            }
            else
            {
                char c = 'a' - 1 + k - (i-1);
                s =  c + s;
                k=i-1;
            }
        }

        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
     char arr[] = new char[n];

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

           if(k>0){
               if(k>26){
                   k = k-26;
                   arr[i] = 'z';
               }else{
                   int temp = k-i;
                   arr[i] = (char)(temp + 97 - 1);
                   k -= temp;
               }
           }else{
               break;
           }
        }

        return String.valueOf(arr);
```

Comment: It is best to include an explanation and justification, rather than just posting a block of code.